# Drupal: Is Drupal 6 supporting APC?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is Drupal 6 supporting APC ?

The reason I'm asking is that I've changed webserver from Apache to Lighttpd and the PECL Progress Bar is not anymore supported.

I've been told to install APC instead, so I was wondering if:

1. does Drupal supports ACP ?
2. if so, do I need to install additional modules ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APC is an opcode cache - all PHP scripts on the server benefit from it automatically.

ACP's `apc.rfc1867` setting allows upload progress to be updated dynamically, which is why APC is suggested to replace the PECL upload bar. Drupal will automatically use it if present.

APC can also be used via the CacheRouter module to store Drupal's content, block, etc. caches, but that's by no means required (or even common).

Comment: @ceejayoz So you are telling me that APC surely enhance Drupal performances, and i guess you are implicitly saying that PECL Progress Bar will work again ? Or is it a bad guess ? thanks

Comment: No, APC is not related at all to PECL uploadprogress.  APC merely takes PHP code, optimizes it, and stores the optimized bytecode in memory.  Also, what do you mean by "not supported"?  You may only need to re-install the uploadprogress module from PECL to make it work again (although that's just a stab in the dark, since I don't know what exactly isn't working).

Comment: @galador @Patrick APC has a feature (apc.rfc1867) that enables Drupal to display a progress bar on file upload fields, replacing the PECL solution. The performance boost is a nice bonus, and APC's general purpose.

Comment: Oh, nifty.  Was unaware of that!  Ignore my last comment, then.  :)

Comment: @ceejayoz Ok thanks, and do I need to configure Drupal as well ? I found this module apparently stable only for Drupal 7. http://drupal.org/project/apc

Comment: You have no need for that module. That is for a particular type of caching, generally used on high-traffic sites. No configuration needs to be made in Drupal to get APC's upload progress to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if Drupal 'supports' APC, because it's more the other way around - APC supports PHP, which supports Drupal.  But I've seen APC used with Drupal on several sites with good results.

Answer (score 0):

In the apc.ini or php.ini file for the Drupal installation, add the following lines:

```
apc.ttl=604800
apc.user_ttl=3600
apc.shm_size=256M
apc.include_once_override=1
auto_globals_jit=Off
apc.num_files_hint = 2048

apc.stat_ctime = 0
apc.file_update_protection = 2
apc.stat = 0
```

These settings will establish a 256 MB APC allocation for the PHP caching facility. Adjust as required for lower/higher values and review the cache timing variables.

Navigate to: /usr/share/pear/apc.php on the web server & copy the apc.php file to the root folder. Then open the page in a web browser at https://example.com/apc.php.

Drupal administrators can access analytics information about the number of cached files/cache requests, amount of free memory, & total allocated RAM usage for APC.